# Member attributes that are functions in C++

Tags: c++, class, function, arguments

I'm trying to teach myself some C++ and as an initial project, I want to create code for performing Newton's method on functions of a single variable. I want to make a class `ObjectiveFunction` that stores user-defined functions for the objective function, the first derivative, and the second derivative.

I want the constructor of `ObjectiveFunction` to take between 0 and 3 arguments, where the arguments themselves are functions:

```
// ObjectiveFunction.h
// Class definition for an Objective Function object.

#ifndef OBJECTIVE_H
#define OBJECTIVE_H

class ObjectiveFunction
{
    public:
        // Constructors

        // Default constructor
        ObjectiveFunction();

        // Constructor with just objective function.
       ObjectiveFunction(double f(double));

       // Constructor with objective function and derivative function.
       ObjectiveFunction(double f(double), double fp(double));

       // Constructor with objective, derivative, and second derivative functions.
       ObjectiveFunction(double f(double), double fp(double), double fpp(double));

       // Methods
       void setObjectiveFunction(double f(dobule));
       void setDerivativeFunction(double f(double));
       void setSecondDerivativeFunction(double f(double));

       double evalObjectiveFunction(double);
       double evalDerivativeFunction(double);
       double evalSecondDerivativeFunction(double);

    private:
       // Storage for the functions.
       // This is the part I'm not sure of.

       // Attempt with function pointers
       double (*objFunc)(double);
       double (*d1Func)(double);
       double (*d2Func)(double);

};

#endif // OBJECTIVE_H
```

How would I create private data members that themselves are functions. I want to create functions objects that (except for being private) would be accessible like `foo.obj_func(3.0)` or `foo.deriv_func(3.0)`, where `obj_func` gets set by the constructor based on the functions that the user passes to the class.

What is the right way to do this? It would be best if there is a way that does not rely on using a pointer to a function object, but I guess if that's the only way then it's what I'll have to learn.

Comment: Function pointers is exactly what you need (because that's what you're passing into your constructors).

Comment: I amended the `private` section of the code with my attempt with function pointers. Is this the correct idea?

Comment: In C++11, you can use std::function.

Comment: @EMS: Yes, that's correct. May I ask _why_ you're using function pointers here? I suspect inheritance may provide you with a cleaner implementation if you're just interested in passing in different algorithms to some common calling code?

Comment: Well referring to my suggestion below, the `LogLikelihood` implementation of the overridden base class would store any data it needs. I'm suggesting that instead of telling the `ObjectiveFunction` class about your functions, you should try encapsulating them in a class which derives from the interface. If you provide an example of how you anticipate using your function pointers above (some example calling code) I can show you a more concrete demonstration of how inheritance could help you here.

Comment: I would anticipate doing something like `ObjectiveFunction obj(*f1,*f2,*f3)`, where I defined `double f1(double x){ return x*(1.0-x);}` for example, and defined `f2` and `f3` as 1st and 2nd derivatve functions respectively. Then (if it wasn't private) `obj.objFunc(1.0)` should return `1.0*(1.0-1.0)` which is `0.0`. I would expect to manually define different `f1,f2,f3` for each different optimization I was trying to do.

Comment: To be clear, I wouldn't want a whole class for LogLikelihood functions. For any given objective function, I would go figure out how to calculate it analytically, and derivatives (or numerically), and then write three functions that perform those calculations. Then I want an `ObjectiveFunction` object to hold them all together. I could subclass, but I don't see what it buys me. No matter what, I always have to supply my by-hand derivation of how to calculate the functions. Whether I do this in main and then pass them to another object that holds them doesn't seem too relevant to me.

Comment: If that's the case then why bother with the complication of function pointers? Why not just call the different functions? Function pointers will work, but if you encapsulate the implementation in a single class and call an interface, you don't have to worry about pointers and the resulting code is a more Object Oriented approach. You're asking about learning C++ but you can do function pointers in C ...so to my mind, an OO solution is more C++ and less C compared to function pointers.

Comment: The idea is to encapsulate the code that applies a function to an input, and to encapsulate the code that repeatedly calls the function and performs Newton's method -- all *without* knowing what the actual function will be before hand. My question is just how can I pass my hand-created functions into this class that encapsulates the way to optimize any generic function. Declaring function pointers as attributes of the class is one way. Then my class calls the different functions without me needing to write explicit function calls to the functions I define.

Comment: You're still defining an interface with function pointers so that's no different to declaring an interface class. I'm not saying there's anything wrong with using function pointers I'm just trying to illustrate that encapsulating the functionality in a class is a more OO approach. Have a look here for a comparison that might be easier to follow than my ramblings: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::function<double(double)>`. This will enable you to store all function types easily.

Comment: Is this supported in older C++ versions? The other commenter suggested it's just in C++11, which isn't on my lab machine currently. I can, and probably will install it, but don't necessarily want a solution that depends on it.

Comment: @EMS: There is a perfectly functional version in Boost or TR1, or you can write your own simple equivalent.

Comment: @EMS: C++03 does not provide a `std::function`. Boost provides a [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/function.html), which is pretty much the same thing as `std::function` and works in C++03. In fact, C++11's `std::function` was modeled after `boost::function`, so they share basically the same syntax.

Comment: @EMS: `std::function` contains no special syntax at all, and the TR1/Boost versions are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices to make here before deciding on an implementation technique....

After creating an `ObjectiveFunction` will you need a way to alter the functions after they've been set? Do you want to be extra flexible about what you accept as a 'function' (i.e. will 'functors' (basically anything implementing the function call operator) be acceptable)? Do you want things that use an `ObjectiveFunction` to be able to use any `ObjectiveFunction` interchangeable regardless of what functions it was given as an argument when you constructed it?

You have chosen a very dynamic approach here. And the only choice you really have to make is whether you use a function pointer or a `::std::function` object. A `::std::function` object can refer to anything that implements the function call operator (such as the result of `::std::bind`). A function pointer can only refer to a plain old function.

Personally, I would investigate having a templatized `ObjectiveFunction`. Partly because then the functions it calls will be set at compile time and the compiler can do a better job of optimizing them. With a root-finding technique you're going to be calling them a lot. So this might give you a significant speedup in some cases.

Comment: By templatized, you mean giving it a template type of callable object? So in most use cases, I would create instances of `ObjectiveFunction<std::function>`... is that the idea? Why does templating like that work better than the amended `private` section of my code with 3 function pointers? In my case, they will only ever be plain functions, but I see the merit it designing it more generally, if for no other reason than I'd like to use the same code for functions that accept and return `float` instead of `double`.

Comment: @EMS: I mean templatizing by expecting a type who's instances are callable as a template argument. This doesn't have to be any type in particular. But if you call an instance of the type as if it were a function, it should work. This is how the standard containers handle things like the 'less than' or 'hash this' functions.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers would work or alternatively, if you're just after a way to allow multiple implementations without changing the calling code, you could use inheritance.

Have a look [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) for a comparison of function pointers vs inheritance techniques.

The inheritance solution would go something like this; First create a base class which implements the interface you want:

```
class BaseObjectiveFunction
{
    BaseObjectiveFunction();
    virtual ~BaseObjectiveFunction();

    virtual double EvalObjectiveFunction(double);
    virtual double EvalDerivativeFunction(double);
    virtual double EvalSecondDerivativeFunction(double);
}
```

Then implement an inherited class which has the functionality you want:

```
class LogLikelihood: public BaseObjectiveFunction
{
    public:
        LogLikelihood();
        ~LogLikelihood();

        virtual double EvalObjectiveFunction(double);
        virtual double EvalDerivativeFunction(double);
        virtual double EvalSecondDerivativeFunction(double);

        // Example of a function to pass in some data which the calculations rely on
        bool SetInputData(double* somedata, int dataLen);
}
```

Finally, to call this code you create a pointer to your base class and point at the implementation you're interested in (in a similar way that you would pass your function pointers):

```
LogLikelihood* pOF1 = new LogLikelihood(); // Create an instantiation of a specific solver
BaseObjectiveFunction* pCaller = pOF1; // Establish a pointer to the interface class and at the specific implementation.

// Now whatever calls the evaluate function can just use the pCaller and doesn't have to worry about the actual implementation.
pCaller->EvalObjectiveFunction(1.5);
```

This will call the two underlying implementations which is (I think) what you really want here.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my use of the class `ObjectiveFunction`. It is a class that *has member functions* which are the actual double-returning functions representing the objective, the first derivative, and the second derivative. An instance of `ObjectiveFunction` would never be called like a function. Rather, I want to access its member functions, `someInstance.d1Func(3.0)`, where `d1Func` gets set depending on what the user supplies when `someInstance` was constructed.

Comment: Apologies, a few typos in there made what I was trying to demonstrate less clear. I've updated the examples above with less ambiguous names.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

class MyClass
{
public:

  typedef int(MyClass::*FunctionPointer)(int);

  FunctionPointer func;

  void Setup(int selector)
  {
        switch (selector)
        {
              case 1:
              {
                    this->func = (FunctionPointer)&MyClass::Test1;
                    break;
              }
              case 2:
              {
                    this->func = (FunctionPointer)&MyClass::Test2;
                    break;
              }
        }
  }

  void Call()
  {
        (this->*func)(10);
  }

  void Test1(int a)
  {
        printf("test1\n");
  }
  void Test2(int a)
  {
        printf("test2\n");
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass *instance = new MyClass();

  instance->Setup(1);
  instance->Call();
  instance->Setup(2);
  instance->Call();

  return 0;
}
```