# Assigning different functions as class attributes using a switch statement in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ Eigen extension for python using pybind11.

I would like one of the extension classes to take an argument which specifies which of several functions the attributes are to use. Part of my problem is that my limited C++ experience means I am finding it difficult to articulate this issue, so I would appreciate any advice on terminology.

In *Python*, a simplified version of I want to do looks something like this:

```py
class My_class:

    def __init__(self, arg1, option):
        self.arg1 = arg1

        if option == 'option1'
            self.operation = operation1
        else:
            self.operation = operation2

    def my_method(self, arg):
        return self.operation(arg, self.arg1)
```

I have tried following the accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864760/member-attributes-that-are-functions-in-c), and have a class with a function as an attribute, though it does not work as intended (explained below).

I have constructed a minimal example to the best of my ability:

```cpp
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include "kernels.h"
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/eigen.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <Eigen/LU>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <math.h>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/SpecialFunctions>

// ================ Functions

Eigen::MatrixXd operation1(Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd> A, Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd> B){
  return A.array() + B.array();
}

Eigen::MatrixXd operation2(Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd> A, Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd> B){
  return A.array() * B.array();
}

// ================ Class

class Test
{
private:
    Eigen::MatrixXd A;
    std::function<Eigen::MatrixXd(Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd>,Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd>)> op;

public:
    Test(const Eigen::MatrixXd &xdata, int k);

    Eigen::MatrixXd operation(Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd>);

};

// class-constructor
Test::Test(const Eigen::MatrixXd &xdata, int k):A(xdata)
{
  switch(k){
  case 1:
    op = operation1;
  case 2:
    op = operation2;
  }
}

Eigen::MatrixXd Test::operation(Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd> B){
  return Test::op(Test::A, B);
}

// ================ pybind11

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(test5,m)
{
  m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin";

  py::class_<Test>(m, "Test")
    .def(py::init<Eigen::MatrixXd, int>())
    .def("operation", &Test::operation)
    .def("__repr__",[](const Test &a){return "<example.Test>";}
  );
}
```

The undesired behaviour is that Test::op is only ever bound to operation2, i.e., invoking the `operation` method in python only ever multiplies the arrays, regardless of if the class is initialised with `k=1` or `k=2`.

After compiling the extension I test this as follows in python:

```
from test5 import Test
import numpy as np
A = np.random.random((5,5))
B = np.random.random((5,5))

T = Test(A, 1)
np.allclose(T.operation(B), A + B) # Returns False

T = Test(A, 1)
np.allclose(T.operation(B), A * B) # Returns True

T = Test(A, 2)
np.allclose(T.operation(B), A * B) # Returns True
```

**Questions**:

- What is wrong with this switch statement?
- Is it sensible to use a switch statement to accomplish this? Do I forfeit any compiler optimisations inside Test::op as a result?

Comment: You say "finding it difficult to articulate this issue", and "though it does not work as intended". Can you state how it actually *does* work? You've described the expected behavior but not the actual behavior, and including that would help articulate the issue. That said, I think @Cornholio's answer is probably correct.

Comment: I suppose it *didn't* work and this is a case of "it compiles so it must work" due to my unfamiliarity with the language. I was expecting passing k = 1 to have op::Test add the arrays together rather than multiply them. The break statements were indeed what was missing.

Comment: Remember that just because something *compiles*, does *not* mean that it *works as you expect* or even "has well defined behaviour".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a `break` after the `case` statements.